# Text box input target iframe

Tags: iframe

I'm an html noob and I just wanted to know if it's possible to make a text box in which you could type a website and when you click submit it will load the website in the iframe of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Answer </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
          $('.frmSubmit').click(function(e)
          {
            $('#dynFrame').attr('src', $('.frmUrlVal').attr('value'));
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="frmUrlVal">
        <input type="submit" class="frmSubmit" value="Go">
      </form>
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="400" id="dynFrame"></iframe>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function SendMe()
{
  document.all.myframe.src = document.forms[0].txtval.value;
}
</script/>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="txtval">
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:SendMe()">
<br>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="400" height="200" name="myframe"></iframe>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried but when I click go the website isn't loaded in the iframe, instead the url in the browser changes but I don't see any changes, just google inside the iframe.

When I type a url into the text box and hit go the browsers url changes to this http://mydomain.com/index.html?txtval=www.yahoo.com

Comment: document.all? Did you stop developing websites around the time IE4 was still popular? -1.

Comment: make the following changes--> <form name="myform" action="post">